# How do I sort my products by most liked on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

If I have an e-commerce site, for instance, where I have a selection of products that each gets a 'Like' button, how would I go about ranking these products in order of their popularity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is, I store the number of likes locally on my own Database.

You can grab the number of likes for a URL from link_stats table:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/

I looked around a lot for a simpler solution, but it's best if you store the number of likes locally. You can update your local value when a user clicks on the like button or you can do it every so often for all URLs if you don't have that many. I personally update the number of counts for all my URLs once every 24 hours.

-Roozbeh

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do it if you have all your products on one page using this tool:
http://www.pagesort.com

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you keeping local reference count (in database) and set up facebook realtime update on those objects. So every time somebody likes your url (object), facebook service will post update to your api. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/